# Using two different functions at the same time in python

Tags: python

```
import time
import random


def timer():
  correct = 1
  x = 0
  while correct != 2:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    x = x + 0.1


def round1():
  numb = random.randint(1, 100)
  print(numb)
  timer()
  ans = input(">")
  if ans == numb:
    correct = 2
    x = round(x)
    print("you did that in", x ,"seconds!")

round1()
```

I was trying to get both functions to run together (have the game playing and the timer going in the background) but as soon as the timer started it would let me continue the game.

Comment: If you want the timer() function to run asynchronously then you could consider multithreading. However, if you do that you'll need some mechanism to stop the thread. There are many ways to do that

Answer (score 0):

In the given program, I have created two different functions that will work at the same time. I have used **threading** to create thread of functions and **sleep** to limit the printing speed. In similar manner you can use game and timer function together.

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

#sleep is used in functions to delay the print
#the below functions has infinite loop that will run together

#defining functions
def func1():
    for x in range(20):
        sleep(1)
        print("This is function 1.")

def func2():
    for x in range(10):
        sleep(2)
        print("This is function 2.")

#creating thread
thread1=Thread(target=func1)
thread2=Thread(target=func2)

#running thread
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```

Comment: This code certainly runs. The problem is that it never stops. How do you propose to handle that?

Comment: @Cobra, I was just giving an example, we can make it limited by using for loop instead of while true.